# Ayuda con mi propio estilo en todos los dispositivos

Tags: android

he estado desarrollando un aplicativo y al momento de probarlo en otros dispositivos con otras versiones de Android diferentes entre todas me aparecen de diferentes colores.

Instale el App en 4 dispositivos cada uno con una versión diferente y tamaño de pantalla diferente de Android y en 2 de ellos me salen las letras color negro los TextView y en los otros 2 de color blanco.

Yo el color se los coloque blancos, no se porque me aparecen negros en otros móviles y eso dificulta la vista con el fondo.

En fin quiero que no se apliquen temas del móvil a mi App y los colores sean los que yo en diseño especifique.

Mi style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppMaterial" parent="Base.Theme.AppMaterial">
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.AppMaterial" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/White</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>

    <style name="floatlabelededittext">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AppMaterial.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="Theme.AppMaterial.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.com.yogo.biometrico"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    provided 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'    
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:viewanimator:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
}
```

2 de los dispositivos tienen Android 5.1.1 pero uno es Huawei P8 y el otro es Samsung A5.

Los otros 2, uno es BLU Studio 5K con Android 4.1.2 y Samsung mini con 4.1.1

He notado que tambien cambia el color, yo le coloco letras color rojo, y el dispositivo las muestra negras.

[image: Error en interfaz en diferentes dispocitivos]

Comment: Asegurate de tener public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Todas las activitys las tengo ej: "public class ActivityCliente extends AppCompatActivity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo acabo de resolver, el problema radica en la dependencia de compatibilidad, intenta con la última estable que es la 23.2.1, te dejo el ejemplo:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema en realidad es que deseas ver los mismos colores en diferentes versiones de OS, he visto que usas **[AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)** lo cual es precisamente para ese objetivo.

Asegura tener dentro de tu `build.gradle` definido un  `targetSdkVersion` a la API 21:

```
 targetSdkVersion 21
```

y como dependencia :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

Comment: Agregue mas info a la pregunta, gracias, mira como tengo el gradle...